# sphinx autodoc remove raises from docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

My codebase's docstrings are set up like this:

```
    """_summary_

    Args:
        dbconn (SQLConnection): _description_
        data_model (DataModel): _description_
        pc_num (int): _description_
        numeric_features (List[str]): _description_
        granularity_levels (List[str]): _description_
        if_exists (PandasTableExistsActionType, optional): _description_. Defaults to PandasTableExistsActionType.FAIL.

    Raises:
        UserError: _description_
        UserError: _description_
        EDAException: _description_
        EDAException: _description_
        e: _description_
        UserError: _description_
        e: _description_
        UserError: _description_
        EDAException: _description_

    Returns:
        Tuple[Dict, Dict]: _description_
    """
```

I want to have my autodoc generate everything but the "Raises section."

```
type_library = ['List', 'Dict', 'Tuple', 'Optional', 'Union', 'str', 'int', 'bool', 'float']

def remove_default_value(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    if signature:
        # Remove type hints from the signature
        signature = re.sub(r":\s*(?:Optional\[.*?\]\s*)?(?P<param_name>[^=,)]+)", "", signature)
    return (signature, None)

def skip_raises_section(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    if what == "method" and name == "__init__":
        # Check if the method has a "raises" section in its docstring
        if obj.__doc__ and "Raises:" in obj.__doc__:
            return True  # Skip the member (i.e., the __init__ method)

    return None  # Use the default behavior for other members

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-signature", remove_default_value)
    app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip_raises_section)
    return app
```

This is my current code inside the conf.py file. I am aiming to remove type hints from the function definition and not generate the raises portion of the docstring. Currently, the removing of type hints works but the skip raises doesn't do anything. I'm pretty new to sphinx and might be missing something. Is this the correct way to go about this issue, or is there something easier/more intuitive?

Comment: The `autodoc-skip-member` event can be used to determine whether documentation for a member should be included in the output. You cannot use it to exclude portions of a docstring. It might be possible to use `autodoc-process-docstring` or `cut_lines` instead. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#docstring-preprocessing